# How to get the insert and delete count with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, integration-testing

I'm currently implementing a way to delete large hierarchies of entities persisted in multiple tables. My goal is to implement a test suite which does the following:

1. Load a big entity tree in the DB using methods as the application does
2. Flush the entities and memorize the insert count.
3. Clear the EntityManager.
4. Load the root of the entities only.
5. Delete the entities with application logic.
6. Assert the delete count is equal to the insert count.

The Test does not have to be thread safe (testcases are executed in sequence). Restriction: It is not feasible to use a in memory DB for this integration test.

I'm looking for a mechanism which would allow me to get the amount of rows inserted and rows deleted since the start of the transaction (no matter whether programmatic, JPQL, Criteria API and so on.) To achieve this I'm using the following solution.

```
class MyInsertDeleteVerifier {
    private final EntityManager em;
    private final int insertsAtStart;
    private final int deleteAtStart;
    private int insertCount;

    public MyInsertDeleteVerifier(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
        this.insertsAtStart = MyStatementInterceptor.insertCount;
        this.deleteAtStart = MyStatementInterceptor.deleteCount;
    }
    /** Called after insert phase*/
    public void afterLastInsert() {
        em.flush();
        this.insertCount = MyStatementInterceptor.insertCount;
    }
    /** Called after delete phase*/
    public void afterLastDelete() {
        em.flush();
        int insertDiff = this.insertCount - this.insertsAtStart;
        int deleteDiff = MyStatementInterceptor.deleteCount - deleteAtStart;
        assert deleteDiff == insertDiff;
    }
}
```

An object of this class is instantiated at the very beginning of the transaction and called according to the comments. The class responsible for providing the counts is as follows:

```
class MyStatementInterceptor implements StatementInspector {
    public static int insertCount;
    public static int deleteCount;
    
    @Override
    public String inspect(String sql) {
        if (sql.contains("insert")) {
            insertCount++;
        } else if (sql.contains("delete")){
            deleteCount++;
        }
        return sql;
    }
}
```

It is registered as the following Hibernate property:

```xml
<property
    name="hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector"
    value="some.package.MyInsertDeleteVerifier"/>
```

The issue with this implementation is that it does not account for batch operations and `@ElementCollection` and JPQLs. Is there a way to intercept every insert and delete in Hibernate and get the amount of rows affected by it? Is there a clean and robust way to ensure a complete deletion of a deep object tree?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not have to create your own statement interceptor and can use Hibernate builtin statistics directly.

According to https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statistics/ you just need to activate the builtin mechanism to get metrics like

```
long getEntityInsertCount()
long getEntityUpdateCount()
long getEntityDeleteCount()
```

even per entity. All you need to configure is the property

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
```

If you want these values displayed or logged somewhere, JMX would be a suitable mechanism: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statistics-jmx/
For this you just configure two more properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.jmx.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.jmx.usePlatformServer" value="true"/>
```

You can use JMX to access the values within the same application, or use JMX monitoring tools (e.g. [JVisualVm](https://visualvm.github.io/)) or JMX exporters to get these values into other systems (e.g. [Prometheus JMX Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)).

Check the [Oracle tutorials for an introduction into JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/index.html).